# 'createPolyglotMiddleware' is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, polyglot

I'm trying to set up redux-polyglot following the instructions here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-polyglot

My problem is that when I add the `const polyglotMiddleware = createPolyglotMiddleware(` part I get an error telling me it isn't defined. I can't work out where I've gone wrong. Can anyone help?

Here is my Reducer code:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { polyglotReducer } from 'redux-polyglot';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    polyglot: polyglotReducer
});


const polyglotMiddleware = createPolyglotMiddleware(
    'ACTION_TO_CATCH',
    action => action.payload.locale,
    locale => new Promise(resolve => {
        // perform async here
        resolve({
            hello: 'bonjour',
        });
    }),
)

const store = createStore(rootReducer, {}, applyMiddleware(polyglotMiddleware));

export default store;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have forgot to import `createPolyglotMiddleware`, try the following on top of you module:

```
import { polyglotReducer, createPolyglotMiddleware } from 'redux-polyglot';
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Obvious when pointed out but I feel a bit grumpy that they don't have it in their documentation!